# User on Windows 7 logs in and gets "green" screen with cursor

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, login

Has anyone come across something like this before?

This is on a Dell T7500 workstation. I can log in as Administrator without any issue. One user account (local login, no domain) logs in, gets the "Welcome" screen and then it fades to this screen:

[image: green screen]

I cannot CTRL+ALT+DEL from this screen. Nothing but a hard power down will get out of it.

I can enter Safe Mode and disable all startup items, and all non-Microsoft services and it still does this. I disabled ALL services (including Microsoft) and it booted to the desktop, but it's basically unusable without MS services. I've uninstalled the nVidia driver, but that didn't change anything.

nVidia graphics card. AVG anti-virus. Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: admin that user?  go into thier startup C:\users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup (paste and change name) see if there is any pranks there.  In the registry start your curser at Kkey_Users search for "RunOnce" (because there are few of these in there) Right above that is RUN, check those. There has to be a better way to admin users runs, Like AUTORUNS will show specific users run items.  I cant think of user configuration items that would do that, and the lack of CTRL-ALT-DEL sounds like something crashed, but users can be locked out of that by GP.

Comment: A user config item, possibly a Theme that is messed up, aero being on if the admin has it off? Disable the Themes service temporarily, that should kill that.